# Scala Method hashCode() on any Int is the same number ?

Tags: scala

Why is it that Scala Method hashCode() on any Int return the same number

Comment: why do you expect another behaviour?

Comment: I assume you mean that ``7.hashCode == 13.hashCode``. Can you provide an example illustrating your observation? I can't reproduce that behaviour.

Comment: @mhs, what do you mean? I don't get `7.hashCode == 13.hashcode`: http://ideone.com/sjWYH

Comment: I think that the question is why is `7.hashCode == 7`

Comment: @EmilH That would have been my second guess :-) But it renders the question somewhat useless.

Comment: @aioobe Me neither, that's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: Why are you downvoting this user's first question? It's a totally valid question.

Answer (score 12):

Because that's how hashCode for an integer is defined.

It fulfils [the contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) quite well:

> - *If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.*

On top of that, it adheres to the recommendation

> - *It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that **producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables***

In fact, this is an example of a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).